# How do I serve multiple files in Node?

Tags: node.js

Here is existing code:

```
var app = require('express')();
var http = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(http);

app.get('/', function(req, res){
  res.sendfile('index.html');
});
```

But now I split CSS in to `app.css` and moved `app.css` and `index.html` to `/public` folder.

How do I serve all `/public` folder? I try `res.sendfile('/public');` but it causes just errors!

Current code:

```
var app = require('express')();
var express = require('express');
var http = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(http);
var irc = require('irc');

app.use(express.static('public'));
app.listen(3000);
```

see pages being served now on port 3000 but no connection to the chat.

Comment: Leave the serving of static files to your sever.

Answer (score 1):

As in Vohuman's comment:

```
var path = require('path');

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '/public')));
```

Comment: Why do I need to install `path`? Is it possible without?

Comment: Of course, you can use `app.use(express.static('public'));` Path is handy when you need to serve more static folders with more complicated, well, paths.

Comment: Add `var express = require('express');` and replace `app.use(app.static(__dirname + '/public'));` with `app.use(express.static('public'));`

Comment: Did you add the express variable to your solution?

Comment: I have it named `app` instead, so I used that, isn't that same thing just different name? `var app = require('express')();`

Comment: No, note the parenthesis in your app definition - it's the 'express' **method**. You need to use the 'static' method of the 'express' **object**. What's more, I just tried what you've proposed on my mashine and got:

`app.use(app.static('public'));
                  ^
TypeError: app.static is not a function`

Comment: Ok I see the pages being served now, but no socket connection ...I update with current code.

Comment: I think you should open a new question for that.